# java - Do every Class violate Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: java, design-principles

I have just read about Singleton Pattern's drawbacks. 
One of the drawbacks is Singleton Pattern violates Single Responsibility Principle, because of policing the instances of itself and providing configuration information.

And I wonder, do every Class in java violate Single Responsibility Principle?
because A Class is a sub-class of Object class and object class provide some default methods such as equals, toString, hashCode. and this class also provide its own operation.

Comment: Does it really matter?  The reality is that that is how Java works, so you have no choice.

Comment: Nevertheless I find this question valid. Maybe you can't change Java but it's still worth to think about it as it gives insight in software architecture.